# Reserve room on hourly basis

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a hotel reservation system where customer can book a hotel on an hourly basis. The problem is that while making a search query I have created 2 tables

1 Hotel_rooms
2 Room_bookings

Now for making a search query, I did the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `room_bookings` 
WHERE  room_id = 103 
       AND check_in_date = '20-6-2018' 
       AND check_in_time != '2:15' 
       AND check_out_time < '2:15'
```

Now this is a very wrong scenario according to this the query is not working properly let suppose a user selects a check-in time of 4 15 PM for room number 103 it should show me result as this room is not available to book at this time as of room 103 is already occupied from 3:15 TO 5:15 so It should show the room will be available after 5:15 or it should show other available rooms at same timings I believe this can be done by making a simple query ? or I am going on the wrong track can Anyone help me out please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your client checked in from 14:00 to 15:00 for 1 hour so this should be your query to check the room is available between that time or not.

The table would be like

```
id  room check_in_Time  check_out_Time   check_in_date
1   102   14:00             15:00          20-6-2018
```

so your query would be

```
SELECT * FROM `room_bookings` 
 WHERE room_id = 103 
       AND check_in_date = '20-6-2018' 
       AND check_in_time <= '15:00' 
       AND check_out_time >= '14:00'
```

Comment: okay so this will return me 0 record means that another client can check in at this time correct? this room will be availeble

Comment: I also want to ask would it be necessarily to use CONVERT('2:15:00', TIME) or without convert is okay ?

Comment: @UsmanKhan it depends what DBMS you are using and the in case of MYSQL there is no need to convert it.